# Open ckeditor with base64 string?

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I have a base64 string. How can I open ckeditor with base64 string as data?

<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="Base64String???">

Or do you know if there is a base64 docx viewer for angular?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the Base64 string into normal string in order to show the human text on any angular editor like `ckeditor`.

Try this:

in your html file:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="base64String">
```

in your ts file:

```
  // the string below is BASE64 encoded:
  base64String = atob('SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=');
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob) about `atob`.

Comment: Hi joccafi. Thanks for your response. 
I tried your answer, but it's not working. 
ckeditor shows "base64string" and not the docx document.